# Using repeat-until to start and stop an action

Tags: delphi, repeat

I want to specify an action to be repeated.

The action is called using a button called spbRewind. Upon pressing spbRewind, Rewind mode is entered. The TimeForRewind is set using a timer set to 10ms (so the action will be repeated every 10ms, in theory).

Here's the code:

```
  TimeForRewind := Rewind and (CurrTime - PrevCallTime > IdealFrameTimeMSRewind);

  if TimeForRewind then
    begin
      repeat
        GotoSaveState(Game.CurrentIteration -4, 0);
      until ???;
    end;
```

I need "until ???" to be "until the button is pressed again," but I'm not sure exactly how to do this.

Comment: No! If you have a timer executing every 10ms, put  GotoSaveState in the timer's event.

Comment: That won't work because of how the project is set up, so I've changed it to this and had the function call its own timer:  

`if TimeForRewind then  
  begin  
    RewindTimer := TTimer.Create(self);  
    RewindTimer.Interval := 200;  
    RewindTimer.OnTimer := GotoSaveState(Max(Game.CurrentIteration-1, 0));  
  end;`  

But, now I get an error (it appears on the penultimate line, on the final semincolon):  

E2010 Incompatible types: 'TNotifyEvent' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped peramater'

Comment: As you can see: comments don't support linebreaks. Edit your question to add (new) details.

Comment: If I could control rewind....... But jokes aside, use a timer like everyone else says. Or run a game loop. If your design is wrong, fix it.

Answer (score 1):

What you said in your comment:

```
if TimeForRewind then
begin
  RewindTimer := TTimer.Create(self);
  RewindTimer.Interval := 200;
  RewindTimer.OnTimer := GotoSaveState(Max(Game.CurrentIteration-1, 0));
end;
```

looks like a memory disaster. Every time you run this code you create a new `TTimer` but you never free them (or maybe you do?)

Instead of constantly creating new timers, and hopefully freeing them, create the timer once at design time or at startup time and leave it disabled (`Timer.Enabled = False`). Then, when you need it, just enable it, and when you don't need it, disable again.

I understood that you want to control it with a toggle type button, so e.g.:

```
procedure TYourForm.spbRewindClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TimeForRewind := not TimeForRewind; // Do you actually need this?
  RewindTimer.Enabled := TimeForRewind;
end;
```

---

Edit after comments

> *Where does the timer exist?*

Assuming you have a form, say you call it `MyForm`, the most easy way is to drop a `TTimer` component from the `Tool Palette` - `System` to the form at design time (just like you would do for e.g. a `TButton`). Rename `Timer1` to `RewindTimer`.

> *How do you specify the intervals?*

Set `Interval` property to 200 (that's millisecs) and double-click on the timer control, which will create an event handler `procedure RewindTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);` declaration in your form, and the implementation stub

```
procedure TMyForm.RewindTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;
```

from which you can call `GotoSaveState(...)`.

> *I'm guessing RewindTimer.Free; is all that's needed to prevent memory issues?*

Yes, but not needed if you integrate the timer in your form. The form will handle destruction.

> *E2010 Incompatible types: 'TNotifyEvent' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped parameter'*

This will go away if you add the timer to your form as described in first point.

Comment: Right, but in your version of the code, where does the timer exist? How do you specify the intervals etc? Also, why leave it sat somewhere random rather than integrate it into the code block that needs it?

The block I've used is copied verbatim from elsewhere in the project (which has been written by other people with way more experience than me); I can't see any code which frees the timer there, but maybe I'm not seeing something, it could be that it's dealt with elsewhere.

I'm guessing RewindTimer.Free; is all that's needed to prevent memory issues?

Comment: Also, how do I solve the 'E2010 Incompatible types: 'TNotifyEvent' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped peramater' error?

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer, much appreciated. I understand everything you've explained as well, but the problem is that the .pas file in which this code is used doesn't have an associated .dfm, so there is no form in which to place the TTimer. Can I place it onto one of the other forms in the project and call it from there? If so, how can I do so without getting any errors?